# angularjs ng-controller in IE8

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-8, angularjs-directive

I testing angularJS app on IE8, and noticed that using version 1.1.5 of angular ng-model directive works well in IE8, but ng-controller does not. I tried everything I could find on the web and nothing.

```
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" id="ng-app" ng-app><head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 8]> <script src="js/json3.js"></script><![endif]-->
```

Comment: Hope you have looked at http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Comment: Did you ever fix this issue @t0ma5?

Answer (score 1):

On `Internet Explorer 8` you need to specify an ID like this:

```
<div id="ng-app" ng-app="" ng-controller="YourController">
```

To work around some of the HTML-processing peculiarities of Internet Explorer 8, you will - at the very least - have to change the HTML in a few places, to add an `ID="ng-app"` information to the root container of your AngularJS-Application. In addition, you have to make sure that your `<a>` contain valid href-attributes.

Comment: Thanks. As you can see I had included id="ng-app". And all of my links inside the ng-controller are ok. 
This is so frustrating..